# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I'm developing an application that go through into user's messages, phonebook lookup and call state.

Application running perfectly where as when i'm getting a call my application crashes.

This is the error some of my user's reported.

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
> me.radhakrishna.buddyreader.CustomPhoneStateListener:
> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
> me.radhakrishna.buddyreader.CustomPhoneStateListener; no empty
> constructor at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2105) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4450) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
> me.radhakrishna.buddyreader.CustomPhoneStateListener; no empty
> constructor at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at
> java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
> ... 10 more
```

Here is my

```
CustomPhoneStateListener.java
```

file

```
package me.radhakrishna.buddyreader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    final MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void phonePlayer(String incomingNumber){
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(incomingNumber));
        Cursor cursor= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String contactName = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();

            String enteredText = "Incoming call from "+contactName;
            String words = enteredText.toString();
            main.speakWords(words);
        }else{
            String enteredText = "Incoming call from "+incomingNumber;
            String words = enteredText.toString();
            main.speakWords(words);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //when Idle i.e no call
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //when Off hook i.e in call
            //Make intent and start your service here
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //when Ringing
            main.stopReading();
            phonePlayer(incomingNumber);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my TextMessageReceiver.java

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

My Manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomPhoneStateListener">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u add this in menifest file ?

Comment: Ya i did see above for my Manifest

Answer (score 1):

The PhoneStateListener is not a receiver, so you cannot put it into the manifest.

Android will send a android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE broadcast if the phone state has changed.

So you should:

```
public class CustomPhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

And put that receiver into your manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomPhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Can u elaborate ? i didn't get what you saying about.

Comment: You put a CustomPhoneStateListener in the manifest, it is not a receiver.

Comment: Here CustomPhoneStateListener.java extends PhoneStateListener how can i extends BroadcastReceiver ? can i take another java file for this ?

Comment: My sample code use a CustomPhoneStateReceiver extends a BroadcastReceiver, which is already another java file. In that file, use your Listener. Did I make this clear?